# About Walter Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis Third Edition" pp.18-19 STEP4 (A5)

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, real-numbers

I am reading "Principles of Mathematical Analysis Third Edition" by Walter Rudin.

At p.19 in this book, there is the following statement:

> Let $w$ be a positive rational number, and $\alpha$ be a cut. Then, there is an integer $n$ such that $n w \in \alpha$ but $(n + 1) w \notin \alpha$. (Note that this depends on the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ has the archimedean property!)

The definition of cuts is the following:

> The members of $\mathbb{R}$ will be certain subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$, called *cuts*. A cut is, by definition, any set $\alpha \subset \mathbb{Q}$ with the following properties.
>
> 1. $\alpha$ is not empty, $\alpha \neq \mathbb{Q}$.
> 2. If $p \in \alpha$, $q \in \mathbb{Q}$, and $q < p$, then $q \in \alpha$.
> 3. If $p \in \alpha$, then $p < r$ for some $r \in \alpha$.

I proved the above statement, but I'm not sure my proof is OK or not.

**Is the following proof OK or not?**

> By definition of a cut, there exist $p$, $q$ such that $p \in \alpha$, $q \notin \alpha$, $q \in \mathbb{Q}$.
>   By archimedean property of $\mathbb{Q}$, there exists $m \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ such that $-p < m w$. So $p > (-m) w$. By the property 2 of cuts, $(-m) w \in \alpha$.
>   By archimedean property of $\mathbb{Q}$, there exists $n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ such that $q < n w$. By the property 2 of cuts, $n w \notin \alpha$.
>   So, $S:=\{m \in \mathbb{Z} | m w \in \alpha\}$ is not empty.
>   So, $T:=\{m \in \mathbb{Z} | m w \notin \alpha\}$ is not empty.
>   If $m_1 \in S$ and $m_2 \in T$, then $m_1 w < m_2 w$ by the property 2 of cuts.
>   $\therefore m_1 < m_2$.
>   $\therefore m_1$ is a lower bound of $T$.
>   $\therefore$ There exists $\min T$.
>   Let $n := \min T - 1$.
>   Then, $(n + 1) w \notin \alpha$, and $n w \in \alpha$.

Comment: I'm going to be really fussy.  Why do you know a set of integers which is bounded below has a minimum?  (It could be that I am being much too fussy then is justified.)

Comment: In Rudin's book, we can use the familiar properties of $\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Q}$ freely without proofs. I guess we can show the property of $\mathbb{Z}$ that I used above without the theory of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: But is that a familiar enough property? Still your proof seems good.  I think I'd use the archemedian principal to prove there is an $n$ so that $nw > q - p > 0$ and as $0*w = 0$ then $n > w$ and ... yeah... you're right.  That's pretty clear that there most be a smallest  such $n$...